# What is the licensing for ART (Android Runtime)?

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-compatibility, apache-2.0, java

Dalvik was licensed under the ASL on the [premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29#Licensing_and_patents) that it was reverse engineered:

> Licensing and patents Main article: Oracle v. Google
>
> Dalvik is published under the terms of the Apache License 2.0.[18]
>   Google says that Dalvik is a clean-room implementation rather than a
>   development on top of a standard Java runtime, which would mean it
>   does not inherit copyright-based license restrictions from either the
>   standard-edition or open-source-edition Java runtimes.[19] Oracle and
>   some reviewers dispute this.[20]

What is, or will be, the license for ART (Android Runtime)?

I believe this is what a [previous question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2248/5058) was intending to ask, but the question wasn't exactly clear enough, perhaps.  I hesitate to edit that question at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The current license is Apache 2.0 overall. And it will likely stay the same way in the future. The Oracle vs. Google dispute has no bearing on irrevocable licenses already granted by Google to Android users IMHO.
Anything else is pure speculation.

Now if/when Google includes OpenJDK code, then additionally the terms of the OpenJDK will apply for these parts. As far as I know it is not clear yet if only the class library or other parts of the OpenJDK would be re-used.